# How to configure tilecache on nginx

Tags: mapnik, geodjango, tilecache, apache

I am running a **geodjango** application with **mapnik** and **tilecache**. Currently tilecache is run on another server to decrease the load on the application server. The application server has **nginx** as the webserver while tilecache is run on the **apache** server. Now we have a requirement that necessitates us to put both the map and application parts in the same server.

Could you please tell me how to configure **tilecache url** in nginx server?

Answer (score 1):

This would work, but it's a poor mans tilecache:

```
# An nginx tilecache
proxy_cache_path /tmp/tilecache levels=1:2:2 keys_zone=tilecache:256m;

server {
  listen 88 default;
  server_name tc.yourdomain.com;

  #root /www/tc;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/tiles_access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/tiles_error.log info;

  add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://tile.openstreetmap.org/ ;
    proxy_cache tilecache;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri";
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 300h;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
  }
}
```